# determine if domain object is persistent

Tags: grails, grails-orm

How can I determine if a domain class instance is persistent, i.e. was loaded from a database? I'm looking for a property/method that would return `false` for this object

```
def book = new Book(name: 'foo')
```

But would return `true` for this object

```
def book = Book.findByName('foo')
```

Is checking for a truthy `id` property reliable, e.g.

```
boolean isPersistent = book.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `isAttached` method or its `attached` property form:

```
def book = new Book(name: 'foo')
assert !book.attached

book.save(flush: true)

Book.withSession { it.clear() }
book = Book.findByName('foo')
assert book.attached
```

If you don't use assigned ids, checking that the instance has a non-null `id` will work but isn't always going to be correct since you can always assign a long value to the id property of a non-persistent instance (it will be updated when saved).

Note that using `isAttached` will fail for persistent instances that are detached from a Hibernate Session - it's only `true` if both persistent (i.e. it was instantiated from database data) and currently associated with a session.